# Using async / wait, UI Freezes after setting content

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, user-controls, async-await

Got some problem and cant't get why it appears.
I'm using .net 4.5 / C# and I try to set Content to a ContentControl after an async function succeeded. 
The main focus of what i want to to in that part of the programm is to switch between an own WPF Loading animation (Usercontrol IsLoading) and a PDF Content (Usercontrol PDFDokument). The PDF is internal loaded & rendered inside the "PDFDokument" and works already very well.
If more information is needed, every asking is welcome.
For you to know i would say i'm still at a beginning level of developing. (the first of three years :) )

```
    public ucPDFDocument PDFDokument = new ucPDFDocument();
    public ucLoading IsLoading = new ucLoading();

    protected async void lstSuchergebnis_DoubleClickItem(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var tempAkte = ((ListViewItem)sender).Content as Akten;

        tbctrlResultPanel.SelectedIndex = 1;
        PDFDokument.IsDataChangeAllowed(false);
        contSwapControls.Content = IsLoading;

        await PDF(tempAkte);
        contSwapControls.Content = PDFDokument; **<-- after executing this line, the ui freezes**
    }

    private Task PDF(Akten paramAkte)
    {
        Akten _tempAkte = paramAkte;
        return Task.Run(() => { PDFDokument.LoadPDFDokument(_tempAkte.akt_ID, ref _DaKsManger); });
    }
```

I tried different ways of using that async loading, but nothing solved that problem.

Hope someone got an idea how to solve that :)

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What call stack do you see if you pause the debugger while it's frozen?

Comment: To get the call stack i inserted a stacktrace & stackframe object to use stackframe.getmethod().name in a foreach-loop. if i pause the debugger exactly after the loop then i get a long list of that call stack, saying
MoveNext
InvokeMoveNext
RunInternal
Run
Run
<.cctor>b__3
InternalRealCall
......
Main
_nExecuteAssembly
nExecuteAssembly
Run
ExecuteAsAssembly
CreateInstance
CreateInstance
CreateInstance
RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone
ThreadStart_Context
RunInternal
Run
Run
ThreadStart"

Comment: When i'm resuming the programm (or startit normally) it exits by an error saying IOException "Control Acess by another Thread as it was built in" (Just like @Xtudio said in his answer but today was the first time i got that exception)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that is async is `PDF(...)`, which you await. Setting the content is not being executed in an async manner. The content you are setting happens on the UI thread. (which is the only way to do so, since you are modifying the UI, which can only happen on the thread it is created on)

Comment: Hmm ok so i need to change the way i'm setting the content to that control. Yesterday i got an idea about using an event or something that way. I try some ways to solve that.